# Get information out of document library to extra list

Tags: document-library

i have a document library on sharepoint with a lot of documents.

I have two clients ( for example client A and client B) who will have access to this document library.

Some of this documents are secret. So client A will not have the permission to see the secret documents.

So i marked/tagged the secret documents with an extra column with "Yes" or "No"

[image]

Now I want to create an extra view OR list (i dont know)  which will show me all the documents which are tagged/marked with "No" in the coulumn "Is this document secret".

And I want to give this list OR view my client A. Only he has the permission for this view or list.

Can somebody please help me. I wached so much videos but did not find the answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using views you will not secure the document. If user is savvy he will find a way to see other documents. Simply put it view is not an security feature (you cannot limit the view per user like you could do it in SQL views). If you need to have items secured with permission I would create 2 folders company A and company B and brake permissions on the folder level. This way customer A will never even see the Customer B folder and their documents.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I was already thinking about that. But to create for every company a folder would be a big administrative expenses, because I will have 50 clients. This would mean 100 folder. I can not handle it.

When it is not possible to realize it in a view, maybe it is possible to tranfer it to a seperate list. Is this possible????

Comment: You could write powershell script to create those folders.

Comment: But I need a SharePoint solution :(

Comment: You use PowerShell to create folders initially then folders can be created one by one in UI as you get new customers. PowerShell is defult admin scripting language for SharePoint.

Comment: I am not able to do that. I am not a programmer

Comment: Does anybody has another solution?